# is it safe to depend on averages

Tags: self-study

An average is a substitute for a complex group of variables but it is not always safe to depend on the substitute alone to the exclusion of individual measurement of groups.How safe is the average?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "safe" and in what context you might be using averages?

Answer (score 2):

The average is a (simple) model, and the purpose of models is to simplify reality such that we can understand it. There is always a trade-off there: if you don't simplify enough you loose the big picture, if you simplify too much you miss important findings.

How "safe" a model is, depends on the circumstances: how complex is the phenomenon you are describing, how bad is an error (e.g. is your work being used to run a nuclear power plant...), etc. etc. So no single answer to your question exists.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "safe"?  The fact that you put it  in quotes suggests you have some concerns about its ambiguity, too.

Comment: Safe is ambiguous. Methods that lead to accident in a nuclear power plant are clearly unsafe, but that still leaves a rather huge gray area. The point I want to make in my answer is that however it is defined, the answer will still depend on the circumstances, and direct her/his thinking towards the complementary dangers of simplifying too little and simplifying too much.

Comment: ' not safe' meaning it is not a true representation of the data set